# understanding and using API's

Tags: node.js, api, reactjs, express

I'm working on a react-express project.

On the back end I made a small API that stream some information on my /API/ routes. Just a JSON object.

The thing is, I do not know how am I supposed to put that information on my front end and use it.

I'm using the project as a learning exercise. I have never use an API before.

My main problem (I think) is that English is not my first language. So when I try to google this issue, I get all kinds of results because I'm probably not using the right words.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically pull the data using a JSON HTTP request. Let's say you have a route `/API/myData` that returns a JSON formatted response. Your server code should like :

```
app.get('/API/myData', function(request, response) {
    response.json(myData);
});
```

On your react app you can pull this data with any request library. For example with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```
var request = require('request');
request('localhost/API/mydata', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(body); // here is your JSON data
    }
});
```

It's just a starting point. You should have a look at express examples, request examples and other similar libraries to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [window.fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) here because it's the easiest thing to start with (even though it's not supported in all browsers yet). You could also use jQuery's ajax function or any number of things.

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org/ip')
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(json => document.getElementById('your-ip').innerHTML = json.origin)
```

```html
Your IP is: <div id="your-ip"></div>
```